# R: use the newly generated data in the previous row

Tags: r, dplyr

I group the observations in a dataframe by ID. I want to keep the value of the first row in each group as it is, while fill in the remaining rows in the same group with lagged values + 2 and raise it to the power of 2. I want to update the lagged values as I proceed.

Please take the following dataset as an example:

```
ID <- c("1","1","1","2","2","3","3","3")
val <- c(1:8)
df <- data.frame(ID,val)
```

```
  ID val
1  1   1
2  1   2
3  1   3
4  2   4
5  2   5
6  3   6
7  3   7
8  3   8
```

I am expecting to see:

```
  ID val
1  1   1
2  1   (1 + 2)^2 = 9
3  1   (9 + 2)^2 = 121
4  2   4
5  2   (4 + 2)^2 = 36
6  3   6
7  3   (6 + 2)^2 = 64
8  3   (64 + 2)^2 = 4356
```

What I have tried:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(val = ifelse(row_number()!=1,(lag(val)+2)^2, val))
```

But what I seemed to get is:

```
  ID val
1  1   1
2  1   (1 + 2)^2 = 9
3  1   (2 + 2)^2 = 16
4  2   4
5  2   (4 + 2)^2 = 36
6  3   6
7  3   (6 + 2)^2 = 64
8  3   (7 + 2)^2 = 81
```

I guess R does not update the value in the previous row before it proceeds to the next row, so it was using the old lagged value. Is there a way to fix this? Also, I have to apply similar but more complicated calculations (a lot of exponents) on a large dataset, so if there is a quick way, it will be perfect!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are pssing two arguments use `accumulate2` instead.
`..1` will represent previously iterated value,
`..2` will represent first argument and `..3` will represent second argument.

*Note `..2` is not used directly here but you are using it for invisble iteration only*

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(val = accumulate2(val, pw, ~(..1+ 2)^..3)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I gave an example which only involved summing... My bad! I have edited the question.

Comment: Based on your comments

Answer (score 2):

You can use `accumulate` to perform such recursive calculation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(val = accumulate(val, ~.x + 2)) %>%
  ungroup

# A tibble: 8 x 2
#  ID      val
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 1         1
#2 1         3
#3 1         5
#4 2         4
#5 2         6
#6 3         6
#7 3         8
#8 3        10
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think this is exactly what I am looking for. However, I needed to change my question a bit so that exponents is involved as well and it cannot be solved with cumsum. Could you please help me further?

Comment: @dianaiii I am not using `cumsum` in my answer. You can solve the updated question in the same way with `accumulate` i.e `mutate(val = accumulate(val, ~(.x + 2)^2))`

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for helping to make it work. And I was referring to another answer, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: a follow up question, if the power of the exponent is stored in a separate column, say column "pw",  how can we incorporate that into `mutate`? I tried `mutate(val = accumulate(val, ~(.x^pw)))` but it returned a vector for all cells.

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
df$val <- with(df,  ave(val, ID, FUN = function(u)
              Reduce(function(x, y) x+ 2, u, accumulate = TRUE)))
```

---

Or using `seq`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(val =  seq(first(val), length.out = n(), by = 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is one option using `Reduce` in `data.table`

```
> setDT(df)[, val := Reduce(function(x, y) (x + 2)^2, val, accumulate = TRUE), ID][]
   ID  val
1:  1    1
2:  1    9
3:  1  121
4:  2    4
5:  2   36
6:  3    6
7:  3   64
8:  3 4356
```