# R: pass multiple arguments to accumulate/reduce

Tags: r, iteration, rolling-computation, accumulate

This is related to [R: use the newly generated data in the previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149165/r-use-the-newly-generated-data-in-the-previous-row/67153147#67153147)

I realized the actual problem I was faced with is a bit more complicated than the example I gave in the thread above - it seems I have to pass 3 arguments to the recursive calculation to achieve what I want. Thus, `accumulate2`  or `reduce` may not work. So I open a new question here to avoid possible confusion.

I have the following dataset grouped by ID:

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
pw <- c(1:6)
add <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8)
x <- c(1, 2, NA, 4, NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(ID, pw, add, x)

df
  ID pw add  x
1  1  1   1  1
2  2  2   2  2
3  2  3   3 NA
4  3  4   5  4
5  3  5   7 NA
6  3  6   8 NA
```

Within each group for column `x`, I want to keep the value of the first row as it is, while fill in the remaining rows with lagged values raised to the power stored in `pw`, and add to the exponent the value in `add`. I want to update the lagged values as I proceed. So I would like to have:

```
  ID pw add  x
1  1  1   1  1
2  2  2   2  2
3  2  3   3 2^3 + 3
4  3  4   5  4
5  3  5   7 4^5 + 7
6  3  6   8 (4^5 + 7)^6 + 8
```

I have to apply this calculation to a large dataset, so it would be perfect if there is a fast way to do this!

Comment: `do.call(rbind, Reduce(function(x, y)if(is.na(y$x))modifyList(x, list(x=x$x^y$pw+y$add)) else y,split(df, seq(nrow(df))), accumulate = TRUE))`

Comment: Though akrun has showed that how to solve it correctly here, still I once passed more than 2 arguments in `accumulate`.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66787554/rolling-computation-of-two-simultaneous-variables-iteratively-or-rowwise-using/66796202#66796202) question if you want to know it how.  Nevertheless, it can be solved by a for loop also.

Comment: @AnilGoyal Thank you very much! It is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we want to use `accumulate2`, then specify the arguments correctly i.e. it takes two input arguments as 'pw' and 'add' and an initialization argument which would be the `first` value of 'x'.  As it is a grouped by 'ID', do the grouping before we do the `accumulate2`, extract the lambda default arguments `..1`, `..2` and `..3` respectively in that order and create the recursive function based on this

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(x1 = accumulate2(pw[-1], add[-1], ~  ..1^..2 + ..3, 
             .init = first(x)) %>%
                flatten_dbl ) %>%
   ungroup

out$x1
#[1]    1                   2                  11   
#[4]    4                1031 1201024845477409792
```

---

With more than 3 arguments, a `for` loop would be better

```
# // initialize an empty vector
out <- c()
# // loop over the `unique` ID
for(id in  unique(df$ID)) {
    # // create a temporary subset of data based on that id
    tmp_df <- subset(df, ID == id)
     # // initialize a temporary storage output
     tmp_out <- numeric(nrow(tmp_df))
     # // initialize first value with the first element of x
     tmp_out[1] <- tmp_df$x[1]
    # // if the number of rows is greater than 1
    if(nrow(tmp_df) > 1) {
       // loop over the rows
      for(i in 2:nrow(tmp_df)) {
        #// do the recursive calculation and update
        tmp_out[i] <- tmp_out[i - 1]^ tmp_df$pw[i] + tmp_df$add[i]
        }
      } 
     
     out <- c(out, tmp_out)

}

out
#[1] 1                   2                  11     
#[4] 4                1031 1201024845477409792
```

Comment: I was grappling with `accumulate2` for some time now, until I realized I had to subset the first elements of `pw` and `add` by seeing your solution. May I ask why we should do that?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR it is because of the way the calculation was carrried out.  If you check my for loop `tmp_out[i] <- tmp_out[i - 1]^ tmp_df$pw[i] + tmp_df$add[i]` it is calculating the power on the previous value of 'x', when the first value of 'x' is already initialized.  we are going to use from the second value for recursion

Comment: @AnoushiravanR it is a bit tricky with `accumulate` to understand the concept.  I would use `for` loop for recursion as it is much more easier to understand and is flexible with n number of inputs

Comment: I understand as I've just started to see how I could use it for a problems like this. Thank you for your explanation, guess I have to first read the documentation.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I think in coding, it is better to get mistakes which will trigger for understanding the why and probably will never forget when you make a mistake and corrected

Comment: I can't agree more with you. In particular when you are unable to answer a question, you can check other contributor's codes and learn from them. Because sometimes that solution doesn't even exist in my mind no matter how much I spent time on it.

Answer (score 6):

In ****base R**** we could use the following solution for more than two arguments.

- In this solution I first subset the original data set on `ID` values
- Then I chose row id values through `seq_len(nrow(tmp))[-1]` omitting the first row id since it was provided by `init`
- In anonymous function I used in `Reduce`, `b` argument represents accumulated/ previous value starting from `init` and `c` represents new/current values of our vector which is row numbers
- So in every iteration our previous value (starting from `init`) will be raised to the power of new value from `pw` and will be summed by new value from `add`

```
cbind(df[-length(df)], unlist(lapply(unique(df$ID), function(a) {
  tmp <- subset(df, df$ID == a)
  Reduce(function(b, c) {
    b ^ tmp$pw[c] + tmp$add[c]
  }, init = tmp$x[1],
  seq_len(nrow(tmp))[-1], accumulate = TRUE)
}))) |> setNames(c(names(df)))

  ID pw add            x
1  1  1   1 1.000000e+00
2  2  2   2 2.000000e+00
3  2  3   3 1.100000e+01
4  3  4   5 4.000000e+00
5  3  5   7 1.031000e+03
6  3  6   8 1.201025e+18
```

*****Data*****

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), pw = 1:6, add = c(1, 
2, 3, 5, 7, 8), x = c(1, 2, NA, 4, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: fantastic and elegant as well.  +1 already

Answer (score 2):

Base R, not using `Reduce()` but rather a `while()` Loop:

```
# Split-apply-combine while loop: res => data.frame
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(with(df, split(df, ID)), function(y){
  # While there are any NAs in x: 
      while(any(is.na(y$x))){
        # Store the index of the first NA value: idx => integer scalar
        idx <- with(y, head(which(is.na(x)), 1))
        # Calculate x at that index using the business rule provided: 
        # x => numeric vector
        y$x[idx] <- with(y, x[(idx-1)] ** pw[idx] + add[idx])
      }
  # Explicitly define the return object: y => GlobalEnv
     y
    }
  )
)
```

OR recursive function:

```
# Recursive function: estimation_func => function() 
estimation_func <- function(value_vec, exponent_vec, add_vec){
  # Specify the termination condition; when all elements 
  # of value_vec are no longer NA:
  if(all(!(is.na(value_vec)))){
    # Return value_vec: numeric vector => GlobalEnv
    return(value_vec)
  # Otherwise recursively apply the below: 
  }else{
    # Store the index of the first na value: idx => integer vector
    idx <- Position(is.na, value_vec)
    # Calculate the value of the value_vec at that index; 
    # using the provided business logic: value_vec => numeric vector
    value_vec[idx] <- (value_vec[(idx-1)] ** exponent_vec[idx]) + add_vec[idx]
    # Recursively apply function: function => Local Env
    return(estimation_func(value_vec, exponent_vec, add_vec))
  }
}

# Split data.frame into a list on ID; 
# Overwrite x values, applying recursive function;
# Combine list into a data.frame
# res => data.frame
res <- data.frame( 
  do.call(
    rbind, 
    Map(function(y){y$x <- estimation_func(y$x, y$pw, y$add); y}, split(df, df$ID))
  ), row.names = NULL
)
```